# How to consume the login returned object 'LoginFunctions'

Tags: priority-web-sdk

According to the SDK,

The 'LoginFunctions' =  This object is returned after a successful login to the server. Use the following methods for this object to retrieve information regarding the Priority installation and API.

But the login function does not return any object.
Can you explain how to consume the object ?

As you can see from my code, the result is not defined.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVLZT.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the image you attached, the breakpoint you are paused on and the "result" parameter are not in the same function scope. Do you get a result if you stop on line 140?
Please share your console output after the login.

You can also check the network tab and see if you are getting any results from the server. If the login is successful you should see results which would be parsed and retrieved as a promise by the SDK.